# What's wrong in my initialization?

Tags: c++, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

This lines of code is part of my c++ cplex library optimization function definition.

```
IloArray<IloArray<IloExpr> > weightedSumBR = IloArray<IloArray<IloExpr> >(env, r);

for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloExpr>(env, r);
    for(int j=0; j<color; j++) {
        for(int k=i*n; k<(i+1)*n; k++) {
            for(int l=0; l<N; l++) {
                 weightedSumBR[i][j] += m[k][l]*x[k][l][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

IloArray<IloArray<IloRange> > range_weightedSumBR(env, r);

for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    IloArray<IloRange> range_weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloRange>(env, r);
    for(int j=0; j<color; j++) {
        IloRange range_weightedSum_BR[i][j] = IloRange(env, 0, weightedSum_BR[i][j], addupto);
    }
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
g.cpp:120:78: error: variable-sized object ‘range_weightedSumBR’ may not be initialized
g.cpp:122:68: error: ‘weightedSum_BR’ was not declared in this scope
g.cpp:122:97: error: variable-sized object ‘range_weightedSum_BR’ may not be initialized
```

Why is this so?
How should I change this?
Thank you

Comment: I assume line 120 is `IloArray<IloRange> range_weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloRange>(env, r);`. Is this meant to be an assignment or a declaration (of an array of size `i`, which is not a compile-time constant)? In the former case: why does it start with a type specifier?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment:

```
IloArray<IloRange> range_weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloRange>(env, r);
```

looks like an attempt to declare an array (which would hide the range_weightedSumBR declared at outer scope.

The same applies to

```
IloRange range_weightedSum_BR[i][j] = IloRange(env, 0, weightedSum_BR[i][j], addupto);
```

I assume you mean those to be

```
range_weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloRange>(env, r);
```

and

```
range_weightedSumBR[i][j] = IloRange(env, 0, weightedSumBR[i][j], addupto);
```

(also removing some extra underscores)

Answer (score 2):

According to the compile errors:

```
 IloArray<IloRange> range_weightedSumBR[i] = IloArray<IloRange>(env, r);
```

looks strange, the `IloArray<IloRange>` seems redundant.
Meanwhile:

```
weightedSum_BR
```

should be

```
weightedSumBR  //you may have typos in your code on variable names
```

and

```
range_weightedSum_BR
```

should be

```
range_weightedSumBR.
```

EDIT:

Comment: I don't think that initialization is the problem. It looks fine and line 120 appears to be 3 lines down

Comment: @JoergB it is really kind of vague.  but I agree with you in a sense.